# Questions regarding facets

Tags: marklogic, facet

I have the following use case :

There are 2 documents having tag 'India' and 'Malaysia' like this :

```
Document 1 :

<Tags>
      <Tag>
          <termId>India</termId>
          <Score>0.89</Score>
      </Tag>
      <Tag>
          <termId>Malaysia</termId>
          <Score>0.41</Score>
      </Tag>
</Tags>

Document 2 :

<Tags>
     <Tag>
         <termId>India</termId>
         <Score>0.88</Score>
     </Tag>
     <Tag>
         <termId>Malaysia</termId>
         <Score>0.91</Score>
     </Tag>
</Tags>
```

I need to have documents which have a tag score greater than 0.7 and also at the same time I am taking the termIds as facets, now when I search for documents having score greater than 0.7, it returns me both the documents but in facets also I get both India and Malaysia with a count of 2 as they are present in both the docs, but instead of that I only want a count of 1 for Malaysia as it does not have a score greater then 0.7.

Is there a way through which i can specify to return only those termIds whose score is greater than 0.7?

I am using the following query:

```
 search:search('(India ) AND ( score GE 0.70 )',
 <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="termId">  
         <range type="xs:string" facet="true">                
             <element ns="" name="termId"/>      
         </range> 
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="score" >
        <range type="xs:string" >
            <element ns="" name="Score"/>
        </range>
    </constraint>
 </options>,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facets show all values for matching documents.

Instead of trying to filter facet nodes, consider whether the tags could be in separate documents.  Can you explain why the tags are in the same document?  Perhaps there is another way to meet that requirement.

Hoping that helps,